# Error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install Dali plugin to eclipse, but eclipes says that its already installed. 
I then tried to install only Dali diagram editor, but after that when i try to create config file to hibernbate i get an error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/jpt/jpa/core/JpaProject
```

I then deleted the Dali plugin.
After that I created a new project and .jars files to lib directory , refreshed project in eclipse, left-clicked to jar file, and got an error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/jpt/common/utility/internal/StatefulCommandExecutor
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you check the Error Log for what exception occurred? Post that if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the plugin after starting eclipse with the `-clean` option followed by trying the same on a new workspace. Also, run an Eclipse update before trying any of the above. Does it help ?

If nothing else works, try starting with a fresh download of Indigo SR2 downloaded from here : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2