# Eclipse cannot rename or delete file

Tags: java, eclipse

In error log:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  org/eclipse/jpt/common/utility/internal/StatefulCommandExecutor
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.StatefulCommandExecutor
...
```

Which package does this belong to? How could I reinstall this package ?

EDIT:
Preference->Run/Debug->Launching->Default Launchers. It's empty there. The Launch Type and it's Preferred Launcher column is empty. Is it normal? If this is causing the problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does rebooting Eclipse fix the issue?

Comment: @Polaris878 That was the first thing I tried. Nop

Comment: Having a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError almost sounds like your installation is itself corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match this Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379473 for Dali JPA Tools. The bug is marked as a duplicate of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385334 which has a lot of discussion about the problem.

The bug seems to occur for several things loaded from Eclipse Marketplace - for example WAS Liberty Profile see http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/367601/

Also see this earlier SO question which is probably the same thing: [Error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948824/error-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project in the `Package Explorer` and go to:

`Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Run/Debug Settings`

In the `Launch configurations for:` box, click on the class that shows in the box and click in edit. Then, fix the package in the `Main class` field.

If there's nothing showinp up in the box, click in the `New` button and setup your main class properly.

Comment: I don't quite understand. There is nothing to be fixed in Main class field. Also, the problem is not project specific. I cannot delete or rename any file in any projects under any workspace in eclipse

Comment: You didn't say much about the problem at first, so I assumed it was a project specific problem, as I went through this few days ago and I solved by doing the steps above. In this case, I recommend you to download a fresh new version of Eclipse here: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. It doesn't require installation, just unzip in the folder of your preference and create a shortcut for it. What about this?

Answer (score 0):

right click on file -> refactor -> rename